# Android studio can not install Support repository and SDK Tools

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-tools

During the installation process, I get this message

[image]

how I can fix it? please help me. I already install it for hours but it won't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you should cancel that, then open Android Studio. Then click on Tools>Android>SDK Manager.

Then download the required components.

I hope it helps.